# Chat bubbles makes to 9 patch images

Tags: android, nine-patch

Please help me for create 9-patch images for chat bubble. Actually I have made 9-patch images of chat bubbles but the problem is text not adjust inside the chat bubbles. so please help me find out this problem.Chat is new for me in android and this is  my  project part so I want to do that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change your 9patch drawables content area as you want, but in your case if you dont want to change it you can apply `android:padding="10dp"` to  your chat buble layout to adjust your `TextView` better inside your chat bubble

Comment: Sir this is link where I create  images. so please recommend me proper way to create 9-patch images for chat. https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: You are using correct tool, please try to use `Content Padding` tool there. and adjust your paddings based on  where do you want your content start from

Comment: This work for me  thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that, please accept my answer if it worked